# Matlab integration with Ruby on Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, matlab

I want to create Ruby on Rails web app (or on other dynamic languages such as Python), that should interact with Matlab. 
Web app sends some info to the matlab server (or simply run matlab file with necessary data if it's possible) that processing this stuff and returns results back to the Rails server. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: If you actually have matlab on the server, you could simply call functions via the command line.

However, if you don't you would probably want to deploy your matlab code. 
After you set up the (free) matlab compiler runtime you can call the matlab functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to want to send info to matlab from a webapp. Then run some process on it using matlab, then it sends the info back to ruby to display it.

No matlab expert but if you did it in python (which you said you could) you could write your results to a database and then read the database in ruby, I expect you can export results from matlab into a database as well.

To use SQLite database in python you can import the module:

```
import sqlite3
```

The relevant documentation is here https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great if you recommend me Ruby's or Python's library, that helps to interact webapp with matlab.

Comment: I haven't used ruby or matlab so I can't give a specific library for that. For python it has built in support for SQLite and includes SQLite in the download files. You can use that as a write point for python and a read point for matlab. Check my edit